# Having to hit enter twice with cin.getline()

Tags: c++, string, try-catch

I know for a fact similar questions have been asked before but I really can't figure out what's wrong with my code specifically. For some reason if I input "n" I have to press enter twice. But if I input "y", everything works fine and the code moves to the next section. My code is as follows:

```
do{
    try {
        if (test) cout << " Re-enter: ";
        test = false;
        getline(cin, choice);
        checkinput(choice);
    }
    catch (int flag) {
        if (flag == 1){ cout << "Error: Input must be y or n."; test = true; }
    }
} while (test);
```

and the checkinput function is as follows:

```
// function for checking the input of y/n
string checkinput(string c) {
    if (c != "Y" && c != "y" && c != "N" && c != "n") {
        throw 1;
    }
    if (cin.fail()) throw 1;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do too much here. You can simplify this.

There is no need to throw and catch exceptions inside `checkinput`. Since there is only two cases you can use a boolean. Secondly, you are returning c. I don't know why you are doing that, it isn't being used. You should instead, return a boolean.

`checkinput` becomes:

```
bool checkInput(string c) {
    if (c.length() > 1)
        return false;

    return c == "Y" || c == "y" || c == "N" || c == "n";
}
```

Now you can simplify the do-while and remove the try statement. Additionally, there is no need for the `test` variable now since we are successfully grabbing *any* input:

```
int main() {
    string choice = "";

    do {
        cout << "Enter yes or no (y/n): ";
        getline(cin, choice); // or cin >> choice;

        bool check = checkInput(choice);

        if (!check)
            cout << "Error: Input must be y or n." << endl;

    } while (true);   
}
```

You may also simplify this further but that will be at the cost of readability. Good luck!